# Manipulating a column of data

Tags: excel

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better title. I have the following input data in a single column:

```
FPC 0
MIC 0
MIC 1
FPC 1
MIC 0
MIC 1
FPC 5
MIC 0
MIC 1
MIC 2
```

And I want the output to be this way:

```
FPC 0
FPC 0 MIC 0
FPC 0 MIC 1
FPC 1
FPC 1 MIC 0
FPC 1 MIC 1
FPC 5
FPC 5 MIC 0
FPC 5 MIC 1
FPC 5 MIC 2
```

Basically, each instance of MIC 'X' has to be concatenated with the earlier instance of FPC 'Y'

Could this be done by using just the Excel formulas, without using Macros?

Comment: `FPC 0` is in 1 cell or 2 columns?

Comment: Its in 1 column, as is all the data. I.e "FPC 0" is in 1 cell.

Comment: And, do you have headers in the first row?

Comment: @GowthamShiva, Nope, no header in any of the rows. But if it helps, please assume a header. Let's say "InterfaceCard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it could be compressed to a single (more complex) formula, the quickest way I can think of is with a "helper" column as such:

[image: screenshot - corrected]

Formula in "B2": `=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="FPC",A2,B1)`

Formula in "C2": `=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="FPC",A2,B2&" "&A2)`

<sub>Note that this assume that the **first** entry begins with `FPC`.</sub>

Comment: When I try the formula for "B2", I get the output as
`FPC 0
FPC 0
MIC 0
FPC 1
FPC 1
MIC 0
FPC 5
FPC 5
MIC 0
MIC 1`

I can see what you're trying though!

Edit: output in the helper column I mean

Comment: @ShoaibMohamed -- let me double check.

Comment: @ShoaibMohamed -- oops sorry, copy mistake.  Formula for B2:  `=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="FPC",A2,B1)`.  I corrected my post.  Let me know if does the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

Little complicated formula, but hope it helps,

```
=IF( COUNTIF(A2,"FPC*") , A2 , IF(A1=B1,A1&" "&A2,SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,A2))  )
```

This formula should start from cell `B2` as the data starts from `A2` with headers. This should work without any helper columns.